# Update() method never called

Tags: unity, c#

I have a class `BlinkingBehaviour` which inherits from `MonoBehaviour`. Game objects attached to scripts containing classes that inherit from `BlinkingBehaviour` should, as the name suggests, blink.

`BlinkingBehaviour` is a small class so I will share the entirety of its code here:

```
public class BlinkingBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Renderer renderer;

    public bool BlinkingEnabled;
    public Color BlinkingColour = new Color(1.0f, 127f / 255f, 39f / 255f);

    protected float CurrentColourScale;
    protected float ColourScaleIncrementPerUpdate = 0.005f; 

    protected const float MaxColourScale = 2f;

    protected void Start()
    {
        this.renderer = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    protected void Update()
    {
        if (this.BlinkingEnabled)
        {
            SetBlinkingColour();
        }
        else
        {
            SetColour();
        }
    }

    protected void SetColour()
    {
        if (this.CurrentColourScale <= 1f)
        {
            this.renderer.material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", this.BlinkingColour * this.CurrentColourScale);
        }
        else
        {
            this.renderer.material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", this.BlinkingColour * (MaxColourScale - this.CurrentColourScale));
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SetBlinkingColour()
    {
        SetColour();
        this.CurrentColourScale += ColourScaleIncrementPerUpdate;

        if (this.CurrentColourScale <= MaxColourScale)
        {
            return;
        }

        ResetBlinkingColourScale();
    }

    protected void ResetBlinkingColourScale()
    {
        this.CurrentColourScale = 0f;
    }
}
```

I have a class `Lamp` which inherits from `BlinkingBehaviour`. I attached `Lamp.cs` to an object in my scene. In my inspector, I checked the `BlinkingEnabled` option, expecting to see the `Lamp` game object blinking after I pressed "Play".

However, the object did not blink.

Here is my `Lamp` class:

```
public class Lamp : BlinkingBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        base.Update();
    }
}
```

After setting various breakpoints, I could see that the `Start()` method was hit in both `Lamp` and `BlinkingBehaviour`. I could also see that `this.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();` returned a valid component.

On the other hand, my breakpoint in the `Update` method in `Lamp` was never hit.

What can I do to fix this issue?

**UPDATE:**

I deleted the `Start()` and `Update()` methods from my derived class. I discovered something new: The `Update()` method in `BlinkingBehaviour` is never called, even though `Start()` is.

Comment: @Bálint by default, `Update` is private, and it can be `protected` or `public`, in this case it doesn't really matter since the superclass' callback is called anyway if there's no overriding `Update` method in the inheriting class.

Comment: @Bálint Why not? Unity calls MonoBehaviour messages through reflection, so they don't need to be public/etc. for it to access them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Update in the derived class should be an override of a protected virtual Update in the base class.

Imagine when Unity reflects the non-public members on your behavior -

```
BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
MethodInfo theMethod = typeof(Lamp).GetMethod("Update", flags);
theMethod.Invoke(lampInstance);
```

Which Update method gets called? By having private and a protected methods that aren't associated as an override, both are available so one will be chosen depending on the underlying implementation - possibly throwing an exception.

The proper way to implement this pattern would be:

```
public class BlinkingBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected virtual void Update()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
public class Lamp : BlinkingBehaviour
{
    protected override void Update()
    {
        base.Update();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I quickly tried your code by copy/pasting it on a test scene, and it's working perfectly fine.

First of all, you can delete both `Start` and `Update` methods from `Lamp`: since it inherits from `BlinkingBehaviour`, both `Start` and `Update` methods will be called anyway from the superclass if there're no overriding methods in the inheriting class.

The fact that `Update` from `BlinkingBehaviour` is never called, tells that there's something wrong elsewhere.

Are you sure that the `Lamp` script component is active?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, the script component is attached to an active object in the scene.

Comment: I don't mean the game object, but the script component itself. Just to be sure, create a new scene, create a simple cube and attach the `Lamp` script and see if it works (it should).

Comment: I have just double-checked -- yes, the script component is active. However, I will use your approach and test it in a new scene as well.